# Ng Grid column totals. Have I done correctly?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid built with following `JSON`

```
[{"TankName":"Tnk1","UseFuel":"100","UnusedFuel":"200"},
{"TankName":"Tnk2","UseFuel":"150","UnusedFuel":"600"},
{"TankName":"TOTAL","UseFuel":"0","UnusedFuel":"0"}]
```

I have configured a NG-GRID to dispay. Grid will display as below
[image]

below is the Grid-otions

```
 columnDefs: [
                { field: 'TankName', displayName: 'Fuel Tank', enableCellEdit: false,},
                { field: 'UseFuel', displayName: 'Use Fuel',  editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-input="COL_FIELD"  ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>' },
                { field: 'UnusedFuel', displayName: 'Unused Fuel',  editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-input="COL_FIELD"   ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>' }

            ]
```

I want to put the column totals (Bottom Row) when user edit something on the gird. I have to show them in "TOTAL" row. I cannot use FooterTemplate since its not suiting my need

Below is my code in controller

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {
            var totalRow;
            angular.forEach(a.gridOptions_all.ngGrid.data, function (row) {                   
                if (row.TankName.toString().toUpperCase() != 'TOTAL') {
                    totalUseFuel += Number(row.UseFuel);
                    totalUnUseFuel += Number(row.UnusedFuel);
                }
                else {totalRow = row;}
            });
            totalRow.UseFuel= totalUseFuel ;
            totalRow.UnusedFuel= totalUnUseFuel ;
        });
```

here a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eYjzIAjJaPvL5r5ovJm0?p=preview). Could some say whether is there a better option

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the picture you placed in the question I would solve it like this:

```
columnDefs: [{
    field: 'TankName',
    displayName: 'Tank',
    enableCellEdit: false,
    cellEditableCondition: 'newFunc(row);'
  }, {
    field: 'UseFuel',
    displayName: 'Ballast Fuel',
    editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-input="COL_FIELD"  ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>'
  }, {
    field: 'UnusedFuel',
    displayName: 'Trapped Fuel',
    cellEditableCondition: 'row.rowIndex != 2',
    editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-input="COL_FIELD"    ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>'
  }, {
    displayName: 'Total',
    cellTemplate: '<div>{{getTotal(row.entity.UseFuel,row.entity.UnusedFuel)}}<div>'
  }

]
};

$scope.getTotal = function(uf, uuf) {
   return Number(uf) + Number(uuf);
}
```

Note the `cellTemplate` and the `getTotal` function.

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qJWw7iILWz69JEw9VLsC?p=preview) to see this updating while you type.

Comment: thanks, i have done it as below, But i guess your way is more cleaner, But in the question I've asked about column totals. so the total should be done for each column and shown in th bottom,

`$scope.$watch('ListOfTanks', function (newValue, oldValue) {if (newValue !== oldValue) 
{ angular.forEach($scope.ListOfTanks, function (row) 
  {row.getTotals = function () {return Number( this.UseFuel) + Number(this.UnusedFuel);}});a.ListOfTanks = newdtat;a.gridOptions_all.ngGrid.init();}}, true);`